# NA's are being plotted in boxplot ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot, na

I'm trying to plot a v. simple boxplot in ggplot2. I have species richness vs. landuse class. However, I have 2 NA's in my data. For some strange reason, they're being plotted, even when they're being understood as NA's by R. Any suggestion to remove them?

The code I'm using is:

```
ggplot(data, aes(x=luse, y=rich))+
  geom_boxplot(mapping = NULL, data = NULL, stat = "boxplot", position = "dodge", outlier.colour = "red", outlier.shape = 16, outlier.size = 2, notch = F, notchwidth = 0.5)+
  scale_x_discrete("luse", drop=T)+
  geom_smooth(method="loess",aes(group=1))
```

However, the graph includes 2 NA's for luse. Unfortunately I cannot post images, but imagine that a NA bar is being added to my graph.

Comment: `ggplot(na.omit(data), aes(x=luse, y=rich)) + ...`

Comment: For a more general case: if the data contain variables other than the two being plotted, `na.omit(data)` will remove observations with missings on any variable. This can have unintended consequences for your graphs and/or analysis. One could use `data=na.omit(data[,c("var1","var2",...)])`, where var1, var2, ... are the variables you require for your graph.

Comment: +1 for @Maxim.K, I ran into this exact problem with a large data frame in which one of the variables had an extremely high proportion of NA values. I couldn't quite workout the syntax to just get rid of the NA in my variable of interest. But note, if you are only interested in one variable, like I was, the code above returns a vector, you must select at least 2 columns in the data.frame to make it work as it is written.

Answer (score 10):

You may try to use the `subset()` function in the first line of your code

```
ggplot(data=subset(data, !is.na(luse)), aes(x=luse, y=rich))+
```

as suggested in: [Eliminating NAs from a ggplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17216358/eliminating-nas-from-a-ggplot)

Answer (score 3):

Here is a formal answer using the comments above to incorporate `!is.na()` with `filter()` from tidyverse/dplyr. If you have a basic tidyverse operation such as filtering NAs, you can do it right in the `ggplot` call, as suggested, to avoid making a new data frame:

`ggplot(data %>% filter(!is.na(luse)), aes(x = luse, y = rich)) + geom_boxplot()`

Comment: How is this different from previous answers?

Comment: It is not using `is.na() == FALSE` or subsetting which are less direct

Comment: How is `subset` is less direct? Also you're using pipe which has nothing to do with this question.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the `filter()` function in dplyr/tidyverse:

```
data %>% filter(is.na(luse) == FALSE) %>% 
   ggplot(aes(x=luse, y=rich)) +
   geom_boxplot()
```

This way you don't have to create a new object.

Comment: did you maybe mean `! is.na()` instead ?  Or do you want all the NA's? ;) Also, you do not necessarily  need to specify `is.na (x) == TRUE` , because it evaluates to a logical vector anyways which will then be used by `filter()` .... P.S. welcome to SOF

Comment: Oh, yep. Typo, sorry.  Thanks for catching that. Also, cool. I did not know you could just cast `is.na()` directly.