# ggplot2: geom_point is sometimes removing NA values depending on the aesthetic used

Tags: r, ggplot2, na

I'm plotting correlation coefficients `r` and sample sizes `n` from a correlation matrix on the same plot (`r` in the upper triangle, `n` in the lower triangle). Usually I have no issue with `ggplot2` removing my NAs before plotting, but in this situation it's only removing `NA` values *some* of the time and I don't know why. I'm using version 3.2.1 of ggplot2.

An example dataframe:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

ex <- data.frame(x1 = c(rep("2010", 3), rep("2011", 3), rep("2012", 3)),
                 x2 = rep(c("2010", "2011", "2012"), 3),
                 r = c(NA, 0.5, 0.2, NA, NA, 0.1, NA, NA, NA),
                 n = c(NA, NA, NA, 25, NA, NA, 70, 50, NA))
```

When I run this graph, with size as an aesthetic, NAs are automatically removed from both geoms:

```
ex %>%
  ggplot(aes(x1, x2))+
  geom_point(aes(size = r))+
  geom_text(aes(label = n))
```

But, when I run this graph, with color as an aesthetic, NAs are only removed from `geom_text`, not `geom_point`:

```
ex %>%
  ggplot(aes(x1, x2))+
  geom_point(aes(color = r), size = 6)+
  geom_text(aes(label = n))
```

This [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17216358/eliminating-nas-from-a-ggplot), isn't applicable because I do **not** want to filter out rows. I also tried changing `x1`, `x2`, and `r` to a character based on [this](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/1584), but it didn't work either

```
ex %>%
  ggplot(aes(as.character(x1), as.character(x2)))+
  geom_point(aes(color = as.character(r)), size = 6, na.rm = T) +
  geom_text(aes(label = n))
```

## Is there a way to make the color aesthetic ignore NAs?

Comment: The two geoms don't necessarily have the same aesthetics attached. They inherit whatever's in the initial `ggplot` call, and then they know the ones that you assign in `geom_text` or `geom_point`, but they don't talk between each other. So if r is NA but n isn't, that only affects the point, and vice versa. Some of the issue is that there isn't a clear alternative: for color it makes sense to make a missing value colored gray, but what size would you expect NA to be?

Comment: As an aside, you can use the `each` argument from `rep` as follows: `rep(2010:2012, each = 3)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the `na.value` value for colour scales.  If you set it to `NA` then the missing points aren't shown:

```
ex %>%
  ggplot(aes(x1, x2))+
  geom_point(aes(color = r), size = 6)+
  geom_text(aes(label = n)) + 
  scale_color_gradient(na.value = NA)
```

[image: ggplotwithnacolour]