# How to remove NA from a factor variable (and from a ggplot chart)?

Tags: r, ggplot2, missing-data

I have a problem with NA in a factor variable since ggplot includes them in the plot as if they are another category/level. I would like to drop the missing data.
I am sorry I don't have code handy at the moment, I tried to remove factor levels from dataset that I found at `data()` and it did not work.

Had someone the same problem?

I tried the solution suggested here [Remove unused factor levels from a ggplot bar plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11403104/remove-unused-factor-levels-from-a-ggplot-bar-plot) but I get an error

> Error: unexpected symbol in: mycode

Can someone suggest something?

Also, if there is no way to remove them from inside the ggplot code, how can I remove the NA from a factor variable?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

assuming your data is in a data frame called `dat`

`newdat <- dat[!is.na(dat$Factor), ]`

not sure how to solve the problem inside of ggplot code

Comment: thank you @Frank , it does work, a question: does it remove the cases with NA in that factor variable across the dataset?

Comment: The command is saying to remove the entire row every time `is.na(dat$Factor)` is `TRUE`

Comment: @baptiste I changed the code to reflect your comment.  I wasn't aware that it worked that way.  Thanks for the comment.

Comment: @Frank, I am sorry I do not understand completely, it removes entire rows every time `is.na(dat$Factor)` is `TRUE`, you mean that I need to call this iside ggplot function, or any other function?

Comment: You could do that or you could create a new object (e.g. `newdat`) to contain your subset of the original data.  Then, use the new object inside your ggplot function.

Answer (score 2):

I'd use `qplot` instead of `ggplot` in this way:

```
qplot(x=column, data=subset(dataframe,!is.na(column)))
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Answers on this related thread:
[NA's are being plotted in boxplot ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17146213/nas-are-being-plotted-in-boxplot-ggplot2)

In brief, instead of the usual:

```
ggplot(data=data)
```

use

```
ggplot(data=na.omit(data[,c("var1","var2",...)]))
```

where var1, var2 etc are the variables you are plotting.

Comment: Simple and clean solution. Assuming there is no differerence between `na.omit()` and `drop_na()`, the latter would be idiomatic Tidyverse, as in: `ggplot( data = drop_na( data[ , c("var1" ,"var2" , ... ) ] ) )`